# Can't bind to LDAP

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to develop an application which uses the same login we use in our company to log in our computer, that is, an Active Directory.
So, I'm sure which is my user and my password but it seems every time I try to bind it throws this:

Warning: ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server

But the ldap_connect success.

So, it must be something related with the username.

I've tried with:

```
$user='cn=username,o=domainname';
```

and

```
$user='domainname\username';
```

Without success. I've admin access to the domain controller so I could find whatever is needed.

Can someone bring some light to this?

Comment: Are you allowed from your current network to connect to that server? Maybe your ip should be in a certain vlan.

Comment: Yes I am. It's a small office with just 30 computers and I can see the pc in the network explorer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not connect when calling `ldap_connect`. See the PHP manual:

> When OpenLDAP 2.x.x is used, ldap_connect() will always return a resource as it does not actually connect but just initializes the connecting parameters. The actual connect happens with the next calls to ldap_* funcs, usually with ldap_bind().

I guess you have some network problems here. One of the following:

- Your web server cannot resolve the ldap server hostname
- Your web server may not connect to the ldap server (firewall issue)
- Your web server cannot find a route to the ldap server (missing routes)
- You've specified the wrong port

Comment: And how could I find where is the problem?

Comment: @Antonio Laguna: the problem is that you can't connect to the LDAP server. You have either the hostname or the port wrong, or it isn't running.

Comment: I think it's some firewall issue. I'll try to figure out how to solve it